# time difference between two machines makes problem in service broker communication

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, time

I have two machines and each machine has a SQL Server instance. Between these machines I run service broker. One of my machines has a different time from the other. I mean the machine time of A is 9:00 o'clock and the other one is 11:00 o'clock. The difference between two times means the message can't be received from another machine. When I sync both times with the same time the messages are received.

My question is how can I configure service broker to skip the time difference?

Comment: Why do the machines have different time?

Answer (score 1):

SSL requires that the time on the client and server be reasonably close.  See [What role does clock synchronization play in SSL communcation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72866/what-role-does-clock-synchronization-play-in-ssl-communcation).

At first glance, it would seem that your servers are in different time zones, so configuring them to be in the correct time zone should resolve the issue.